# Execute command in bash with parameter and return value

Tags: bash, scripting

I have the following script to check if a NFS mount is currently mounted on the server :

```
#!/bin/bash
$targetserver=192.168.3.1
commandline="mount | grep '$targetserver' | wc -l"
checkmount=`$commandline`

if [ $checkmount == "1" ]; then
  echo "Mounted !"
else
  echo "Not mounted"
fi
```

But it seems that my checkmount is not returning anything.

What am I missing here ?

Comment: What do you get if you run the `mount | grep ...` bit on the command line?

Comment: returns '0' if not mounted, '1' if mounted. Just counting the lines

Comment: Just to be safe shouldn't you check >= 1 in case you have more folders mounted from the same NFS.

Comment: @Matt: good point, will check that.

Comment: @jgr has already put in a good answer, but I was going to suggest echoing the `checkmount` variable to make sure it's got the value you expect (i.e. 0 or 1). That's generally a good way to debug scripts.

Comment: Please see [BashFAQ/050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) (avoid putting commands in variables) and [BashFAQ/082](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082) (why `$()` is better than backticks).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should work better.

```
#!/bin/bash
targetserver="192.168.3.1"
commandline=$(mount | grep "$targetserver" | wc -l)

if [ $commandline -gt 0 ]; then
  echo "Mounted !"
else
  echo "Not mounted"
fi
```

You could shorten it down though, using `$?`, redirection and control operators.

```
targetserver="192.168.3.1"
mount | grep "$targetserver" > /dev/null && echo "mounted" || echo "not mounted"
```

Depending on system `grep /etc/mtab` directly might be a good idea too. Not having to execute `mount` would be cleaner imho.

Cheers!

Comment: Is there any reason to prefer `$(...)` syntax over backtick syntax? Just interested.

Comment: afaik backticks are more portable, i.e `/bin/sh` knows about them too.

Comment: @Cameron  $() syntax is much easier to nest, and generally more readable. Backticks are slightly more portable, but almost no modern machine doesn't have a shell installed that accepts $() notation, which has been standardized for nearly 20 years.   (/bin/sh on Solaris is the classic example, but /xpg4 contains plenty of modern shells)  Recently, the autoconf maintainer (autoconf is notorious for portability concerns) has agreed that $() is acceptable.  There is almost no reason for anyone to ever use backticks anymore.

Comment: I would have carried forward `checkmount` for the variable name. It's more meaningful in the context than "commandline".

Answer (score 3):

I'd maybe do this, or just but the content of the function directly in `if`, if you just use it in one place.

```
nfsismounted() {
mount | grep -qm1 "$1":
}
```

q = quiet (we just want the return code), m1 = quit on first match.

And use it as such:

```
if nfsismounted 192.168.0.40; then
    echo "Mounts found"
else
    echo "Not mounts"
fi
```

A side note on the code in your question, you don't test with == in the shell, just =. == Will break on, for example, dash which is /bin/sh in Debian/Ubuntu since a while.

**Edit**: For added portability (non-GNU grep), remove the flags on *grep* and `> /dev/null`. Tests were done on bash/dash/ksh